# UX: Working with large datasets using data grids

Tags: .net, datagrid, paging, user-experience

I've found similar questions here, but I'd like to extend it a bit.

I'm pretty struggling in grasping a proper UX concept (Windows Forms, .NET) for working with large data sets (10,000+ records, generally is safe to assume up to 100,000 recs.). I would like to enable users (of the internal registration system) to browse the dataset as seamlessly as possible.

My dataset is located on remote server and can be accessed concurrently by multiple users with per-record locking. I'm using RPC, so no direct databinding is possible and I have to load data by myself in code.

I've tried these approaches (all currently implemented using GridEX data grid):

1. Loading all the records at once (currently 7,6k records, takes up to 15 seconds to load), presenting user with loading dialog in duration of the loading process. The problem is, data takes around 20M of memory and I'm afraid of the memory consumption issues later on, as the dataset grows.
2. Manually handling paging on GridEX (or any other grid) with special datasource, that loads only portion of the data from server. This allows me to manage amount of memory consumed, but presents multiple limitations to user and also, as the grid by default does not handle paging, there are some issues with searching, etc.

My question is, HOW it should be done properly? Assuming, that client wants to be able to browse the dataset, so search & filter dialog is not that much an option.

I know, this is not a proper Q&A question and I'm hoping of a multitude of subjective opinions, so it will be hard to mark an answer.

Thank you for your insights.